# Declared boolean on object, doesn't change his value

Tags: java, instance-variables

I was just figuring out how instance variables are working, but it lead me to something strange.

```
public class DrumKit {
    boolean topHat = true;
    boolean snare = true;

    void playTopHat() {
        System.out.println("ding ding da-ding");
    }

    void playSnare(){
        System.out.println("bang bang ba-bang");        
    }
}

public class DrumKitTestDrive {
    public static void main(String [] args) {

        DrumKit d = new DrumKit();
        d.playSnare();
        d.snare = false;
        d.playTopHat();

        if (d.snare == true);{
            d.playSnare();  
        }
    }
}
```

How is it possible that it outputs:
"bang bang ba-bang
ding ding da-ding
bang bang ba-bang"

And not: "bang bang ba-bang
ding ding da-ding"

Because what I thought was that the snare only would play once because I'm declaring it after d.playSnare();
to d.snare = false;

Answer (score 6):

Remove the semicolon in this line, which is acting as the body for your `if` block.

```
if (d.snare == true);{
```

Change it to

```
if (d.snare == true){
```

Also, `d.snare` is already a `boolean`, so you can simplify the conditional expression to:

```
if (d.snare){
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the bang

```
if (d.snare == true);
```

Remove ;